# Openshift scaling best practices

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

Could you help me in one thing?

I have got a project with few deployments - databases, app1, app2, monitoring etc.
I have a very specific system that needs to be scaled with multiple metrics that are stored in monitoring system.
I have created a small microservice which checks if conditions are met (it's not something like simple GET - there is a whole algorithm that calculates it) and scales the environment (oc app or curl - it doesn't matter at this point).

Here's my question - is it a good solution? I wonder if it can be done in a better way.
And the second one - is it okay to create new serviceaccount with edit role just to perform scaling?

I know it's not complicated when you have some experience in openshift but this system is so specific (autoscaling managed by algorithms) that I couldn't find anything useful in docs.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. It is fine to create a seperate service account with ``edit`` role for just the monitoring app which triggers the scaling. Recommended over giving ``edit`` to ``default`` service account.

Comment: You might also look at using custom metrics with horizontal pod autoscaler, although not sure if that is actually usable yet with custom metrics. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-custom-metrics

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just wanted to know that I didn't do something stupid in the architecture. Thanks for the hint with autoscaler - I'm pretty sure it won't work with my metrics but I'll check it. Thanks! :)